# How to use RegEX expression for a integer field in Odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I am using one simple code to validate a integer field in Odoo. I tried with the following code. But nothing seems to affect the field validation.

```
class ExtraKnivesSub(models.Model):
    _name = 'extra.knives.sub'
    _description = 'Extra Knives Sub'

    x_extra_knives_sub = fields.Integer('Number of Knives',required=True)
    x_upcharge_sub = fields.Float('Up-Charge',digits='EF Price')
    x_extraknives_m = fields.Many2one('extra.knives')

    @api.constrains('x_extra_knives_sub')
    def _check_number(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.x_extra_knives_sub and not re.match(r'^[0-9]+$', rec.x_extra_knives_sub):
                raise ValidationError(_('Extra Knives should only contains numbers.'))
```

Any help to get my mistake rectified will be really helpful.

Comment: Odoo does have a validation for integer fields.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the python debugger to inspect your code and tell me please the result of your investigation :

```
@api.constrains('x_extra_knives_sub')
def _check_number(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.x_extra_knives_sub
            is_digits_only = re.match(r'^[0-9]+$', rec.x_extra_knives_sub)               
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            if not is_digits_only:
               raise ValidationError(_('Extra Knives should only contains numbers.'))
```

How to use pdb: https://www.slideshare.net/noelled/debugging-python-pdb-ndaley-50574986
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBP1K0kiC5E